# Save category with childs in Core Data of custom object type

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

This is JSON response:

[image: JSON Response]

I have to store categories with childs in Core Data. Should I use Transformable type for childs?

Here, category and child classes are the same in Core data.

How can I do this? Any help?

Here is my Core data model structure:

[image]

Comment: `childs` should be a to-many relationship to Category and the reversed to-one relationship should be named `parent`

Answer (score 0):

One to many relationships is the answer you are looking for as they were made for this use case. The category entity will be the parent and the sub-Category entity will the child.

The parent category entity will have a to-many relationship with the subcategory entity, please make sure that you add an inverse relationship as well from the child to parent.

And what most devs forget about is the delete rule, do think about what should happen to the parent when a subcategory is deleted or when a category itself is deleted.

I am sharing some of the tutorials and I hope they are helpful

Core data delete rule: https://cocoacasts.com/core-data-relationships-and-delete-rules/

Core data one to many relationship: https://cocoacasts.com/one-to-many-and-many-to-many-core-data-relationships/